# External user not able to login in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps environment connected to my Microsoft Account (@outlook.com) for years.
Now I want to add an external user to Azure DevOps. This user has a private (Microsoft) account (@live.nl) and a business account. I'm able to add his private account but not his Business (office 365) account. He doesn't get a welcome email as well. But Azure DevOps says successfully send...

The business account user (and of course the private account) is visible under Users (https://myorganisation.visualstudio.com/_settings/users). It has a free basic license and it has access to one of the projects.

Because this didn't work, I also added my own business account on exactly the same way and that works instantly. I get the welcome email and I can login to the project.

I also followed this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-external-user?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav) to add external users but the Guest setting under policy is not there for me. Also, why can I add then my own business account?

Any idea's??

Comment: He @jessehouwing, no the address is not the same. We use his private account right now so we could continue.

Comment: Added some extra details to the question

Comment: did you try to check the emails in spams ?

Comment: @Jayendran yes checked spam. If user logs in, he get's unauthorized

Comment: See the [issue on Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/2881) for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved by Microsoft in Azure DevOps. Apparently something was wrong configured in Azure DevOps on user level. They fixed the bug and fixed the problem with the account.